# pandas: How to detect an index of a series that does not have numerical value?

Tags: pandas

I have a series like below:

```
0.0       1243340641
1.0          4403140
2.0       1243340592
3.0       3181787143
4.0        148623845
5.0        148623662
             ...    
5046.0    3181981603
5047.0    1436718983
5048.0    1436719026
5049.0    1436719067
5050.0    1436719283
5051.0    3181984143
```

I believe that it should be `int64` dtype, but in fact `pandas` considered the series as `object`.

I want to detect which row that makes the pandas consider the series as `object` dtype?

Comment: What do you mean by "considered the series as `object`"? where did you get the series, `read_csv` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think need if mixed values - numeric with strings:

```
print (s[s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))])
```

If want return all non string values:

```
print (s[~s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))])
```

Or integer values:

```
print (s[s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int))])
```

**Sample**:

```
s = pd.Series(['1243340641',4403140,1243340592,'3181787143'], index=[0,1.0,2.0,3.0])
print (s)
0.0    1243340641
1.0       4403140
2.0    1243340592
3.0    3181787143
dtype: object

print (s[s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))])
0.0    1243340641
3.0    3181787143
dtype: object

print (s[~s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))])
1.0       4403140
2.0    1243340592
dtype: object

print (s[s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int))])
1.0       4403140
2.0    1243340592
dtype: object
```

Comment: It shows me nothing? When I use ``print(s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))`` it returns almost True. I would like to print only rows that are not numeric.

Comment: @TiếuThủy - hmmm, maybe all values are strings, can you check edited answer?